# Convert numpy arrays in a nested dictionary into list whilst preserving dictionary structure

Tags: python, json, numpy, dictionary

I am looking for a way how to dump nested dictionary containing numpy arrays into JSON file (to keep full logs of my experiments and data in one place).

My dictionary looks like this (the structure may be more nested than the code displayed):

```
import numpy as np
data = {'foo': {'bar': np.array([1, 2, 3])}, 'goo': np.array([3,5,7]),'fur': {'dur': {'mur': np.array([7,5,8])}}}
```

At the moment this code fails because numpy array is not serializable:

```
with open('data.txt','w') as fl:
    json.dump(data,fl)
```

I know it is possible to use tolist() function but I do not know how to walk over the dictionary whilst preserving the structure of data and exchanging np.arrays for list.

I tried getting individual values from the dictionary using recursion but I do not know how to "build the dictionary back". My code at the moment (without json dump):

```
import numpy as np

def dict_walk(data):
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dict_walk(v)
        else:
            l = v.tolist()
            print l

data = {'foo': {'bar': np.array([1, 2, 3])}, 'goo': np.array([3,5,7]),'fur': {'dur': {'mur': np.array([7,5,8])}}}
dict_walk(data)
```

Comment: You might also want to consider using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which lets you save a Python object directly.  (The question is still worthwhile, of course, just wanted to point out another method in case you hadn't heard of it).

Comment: @ASGM Thanks for the suggestion! I am using JSON for the compatibility with third party software so I decided against pickle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can give `json.dump` a `default` function; it is called for any data type that JSON doesn't know how to handle:

```
def default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
        return obj.tolist()
    raise TypeError('Not serializable')

with open('data.txt','w') as fl:
    json.dump(data, fl, default=default)
```

Comment: @jmetz: ah, never mind. Numpy is being obtuse with its type system; `np.array()` produces objects of type `np.nparray()` that use `array` as the name in their `repr()` output. Yay.